# Using both Do While and Loop until in the same time

Tags: vba, loops

Will this cause any problems?

```
iCarli = 1

Do While .SelectSingleNode("//ROWSET/ROW/VENDORPARTNUM" & CStr(iCarli)).Text <> EMPTY_STRING

    'Statements here for setting up array and its assignment

    iCarli = iCarli + 1

Loop Until iCarli = 10
```

The point here being that I need to use the two conditions, node is not empty and the counter cannot exceed 9 without throwing some unforeseen error.
(I know that I could use the `If iCarli = 10 Then Exit Do`).

Thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Never mind.  The answer is no. Compiling it throws a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that will cause problems. The IDE will not accept it as valid syntax. You can either Do While/Until or Loop While/Until, but not both. But you can just put in a test at the bottom of the loop to exit:

```
Sub WillNotWork()
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1&
    Do While i > 1&

        i = i + 1&

    Loop Until i > 10&
End Sub

Sub InsteadUse()
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1&
    Do While i > 1&
        i = i + 1&
        If i > 10& Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```